# Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage

Am getting this error "Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document." when i enable "Block third-party cookies" from browser

Is that any other alternative solution for to store data from browser?

```
// To set value to localstorage
sessionStorage.setItem("contact", 'Found');
// To get value to localstorage
sessionStorage.getItem("contact");
```

Comment: I have checked this solution, but its not related to my problem. refer my screenshot : https://prnt.sc/oj82un

Comment: Note that, if you are accessing storage inside of an iframe, it is considered as "third party"